# how to create a vagrant box from vmware image with packer

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, packer

I have a VMWARE image running CentOS.I want to create a vagrant box from it with packer. I am new to Vagrant and can anyone suggest the steps?

Answer (score 3):

Using Packer to apply additional provisioning steps to an existing VM is supported by Packer via the [vmware-vmx builder](https://packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-vmx.html)

> This VMware Packer builder is able to create VMware virtual machines
>   from an existing VMware virtual machine (a VMX file). It currently
>   supports building virtual machines on hosts running VMware Fusion
>   Professional for OS X, VMware Workstation for Linux and Windows, and
>   VMware Player on Linux.

In your situation where you have an existing CentOS VMX and want to turn it into a Vagrant box you would create packer.json configuration file like so:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "vmware-vmx",
    "source_path": "/path/to/a/vm.vmx",
    "ssh_username": "root",
    "ssh_password": "root",
    "ssh_wait_timeout": "30s",
    "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
  }],
  "provisioners": [{
    "type": "shell",
    "inline": ["echo 'my additional provisioning steps'"]
  }],
  "post-processors": [{
    "type": "vagrant",
    "keep_input_artifact": true,
    "output": "mycentos.box"
  }]
}
```

Packer would clone the source VMX, boot the box, apply any provisioning steps you had, shut down the box, and then output a new Vagrant ".box" file.

Comment: thanks. However, I got an error "Build 'vmware-vmx' errored: Timeout waiting for SSH.". The ssh username and password are correct. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you won't be able to.
Packer assumes a base box (for vagrant) and ends at a new box. You can't go from a running VM to a box via Packer.

If you started the CentOS VM using vagrant, you can do  `vagrant export`
If you have a running VM you made manually, your best bet is to start over using a Vagrant box. If you want to continue with this route: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vmware/boxes.html